# How to add value if exists in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have table_a which has a foreign key column referencing table_b.  I'd like to fill the fkey column with values from column_a if the value exists in table_b's pkid column but null if it doesn't exist.

Without looking for whether it exists, I was using the following query:

```
UPDATE table_a SET fkey = column_a;
```

That fails sometimes due to the foreign key constraint if column_a's value doesn't exist in table_b so I think I need to use some combination of CASE and EXISTS but I'm struggling with the syntax.

The constraint looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_a ADD CONSTRAINT
    constraint_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fkey) REFERENCES table_b(pkid);
```

Comment: I would suggest you not to use two columns to store the same thing. Drop `column_a` after you complete the operation.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing, it is NULL when the values don't exist in table_b and only the value of column_a when they do.  Column_a is being preserved because it is coming from the original flat file import.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column contains null in all rows, you can join `table_b` on `a.column_a = b.pkid`:

```
update table_a a 
set fkey = column_a
from table_b b
where a.column_a = b.pkid
```

or check in a subquery whether `b.pkid` exists:

```
update table_a
set fkey = column_a
where exists (
    select pkid
    from table_b
    where pkid = column_a)
```

If you have to set null in appropriate rows you can use `exists` in `case`:

```
update table_a
set fkey = (select case
    when exists (
        select pkid
        from table_b
        where pkid = column_a)
    then column_a
    end)
```

Comment: This doesn't set the value to NULL when there is no match.  That's the trick and an important step here.  There will be other values in fkey before this SET operation.

Comment: I was convinced (unjustifiably) that it was a newly created column. See the updated answer.